# SAX-based parser not seeking content

Tags: php, xml, parsing, sax

I am trying to implement a SAX based parser but somehow it only recognizes the start of the element and the end, the content is not provided in the logs. The variable holding the XML is filled correctly, I checked through a simple log.
Here is the code:

```
<?php
    function startElementHandler($parser, $name, $attribs) {
       if($name == "id"){
            $id = TRUE;
        }
    }

    function endElementHandler($parser,$name){
        $id = FALSE;
    }

    function characterDataHandler($parser,$data){
        if($id == TRUE){
            echo $data;
        }
    }

    global $id;
    $id = FALSE;

    $parser = xml_parser_create();
    xml_set_element_handler($parser, "startElementHandler","endElementHandler");
    xml_set_character_data_handler($parser,"characterDataHandler");

    $xml = file_get_contents("http://itunes.apple.com/de/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=100/xml");
    xml_parse($parser,$xml);

    //xml_parser_free($parser);
?>
```

Any suggestion how I could recieve the content? Maybe I am missing something strange I am not aware of at the moment. 
best regards
tim

Comment: Are you sure $id becomes true? And if so, can you please post that part of the XML.

Comment: mhm, yea, strangly $id never becomes true...any suggestions why it wont?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your comment, `$id` never becomes true. Maybe you want attribs to have an id and not the name of the element. For example, if you have the XML

```
<div id="x"> blah </div>
```

You get

```
$name="div", $attribs={"id":"x"}
```

(this came out a bit of php-python, but i hope you get my point)

Is that really your bug?

According to http://www.phpcatalyst.com/php-compare-strings.php you should always compare strings using `===`. Is that your bug?

Answer (score 1):

You only used the [`xml_set_element_handler`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xml-set-element-handler.php)-callbacks. Those only:

> Set up start and end element handlers

If you also want to retrieve the content of those tags, you'll also need to register the [`xml_set_character_data_handler`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xml-set-character-data-handler.php)-callback. Because this one:

> Set up character data handler

Comment: as you can see I just set up the character data handler.

Comment: What is the output you're getting?